# Thunderbird extension code not returning all the threads

Tags: api, native, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I am using the below code and expecting to retrieve all the messages belonging to the same thread. However, it always returns only the selected message details. The message is already an hour old so indexing should be done. Also i tried this on multiple threads but same result. Please advise whats wrong here

```
this.query =
Gloda.getMessageCollectionForHeaders([msgHdr], {
onItemsAdded: function (aItems) {},
onItemsModified: function () {},
onItemsRemoved: function () {},
onQueryCompleted: function (aCollection) {
add("\t\t\t/---------------------------\\\n");
add("\t\t\t| vik Gloda results |\n");
add("\t\t\t\\---------------------------/\n\n");

add("Gloda found "+aCollection.items.length+" items\n");
// Iterator over the messages Gloda found...
for each (let [i, glodaMsg] in Iterator(aCollection.items)) {
add("This message is from: "+glodaMsg.from+"\n");
add("This message is to: "+glodaMsg.to+"\n");
add("This message is from lists: "+glodaMsg.mailingLists+"\n");

}
},
}, true)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

See the last paragraph of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Thunderbird/Creating_a_Gloda_message_query?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Thunderbird%2FCreating_a_Gloda_message_query ; in your case, you need to launch a second query by doing glodaMsg.conversation.getMessageCollection. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Thunderbird/Gloda_examples?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Thunderbird%2FGloda_examples has a bigger example.